# Wunderbit webhook message from python

Tags: python, request

I try to send webhook alerts to wunderbit (crypto trading platform), but i receive
<Response 403> error. Please help.

My code:

import requests

target_url= "https://wundertrading.com/bot/exchange"
message = "My open long command(generated by wunderbit)"

my_request = requests.get(target_url, data = message, headers = {"Content-Type": "text/plain"})
print(my_request)

Comment: I already try with requests.post(), but still not work..

Answer (score 0):

were you trying to send a signal from a custom server?
Only signals from TradingView were allowed previously. Now you can send a custom signal, but you will need to whitelist your IP first. see [WunderTrading documentation](https://help.wundertrading.com/en/articles/6542237-send-signals-from-your-server)